# iTunes Match constantly have to sign out/in

Tags: itunes, keychain, itunes-match

Running the latest version of mavericks and iTunes and my library is about 6000+ songs.

But after a few days of listening iTunes will prompt me to sign out and back in for match to work. Sometimes closing the app and opening it up again will avoid the issue. But typically after a week or two iTunes match will not work until I sign out and back in again. This typically solves the issue,

Here is the console log when I open iTunes and its prompting me to sign into iTunes match again because there was "an error".

```
7/22/14 10:09:51.961 AM iTunes[86044]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_WRITE] delete: "No such file or directory" - 0x2
7/22/14 10:09:57.764 AM gkbisd[256]: Unable to collect cdhash for /Applications/iTunes.app (error code 100024)
7/22/14 10:09:59.988 AM com.apple.usbmuxd[67]: LOCKDOWN_V2_BONJOUR_SERVICE_NAME is _apple-mobdev2._tcp,936707f4
7/22/14 10:09:59.989 AM com.apple.usbmuxd[67]: _SendAttachNotification Device 30:10:e4:83:bb:a6@fe80::3210:e4ff:fe83:bba6._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local. has already appeared on interface 4. Suppressing duplicate attach notification.
7/22/14 10:09:59.989 AM com.apple.usbmuxd[67]: _SendAttachNotification Device 30:10:e4:83:bb:a6@fe80::3210:e4ff:fe83:bba6._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local. has already appeared on interface 4. Suppressing duplicate attach notification.
7/22/14 10:09:59.990 AM com.apple.usbmuxd[67]: _SendAttachNotification Device 30:10:e4:83:bb:a6@fe80::3210:e4ff:fe83:bba6._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local. has already appeared on interface 4. Suppressing duplicate attach notification.
**** BAG END ****
7/22/14 10:10:01.932 AM iTunes[32751]: ApplePushService: APSConnection being used without a delegate queue
7/22/14 10:10:02.198 AM com.apple.SecurityServer[16]: Session 100169 created
7/22/14 10:10:37.194 AM iTunes[32751]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:269
7/22/14 10:10:37.195 AM iTunes[32751]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:269
7/22/14 10:10:37.195 AM iTunes[32751]: tid:1f10b - Mux ID not found in mapping dictionary
7/22/14 10:10:37.195 AM iTunes[32751]: tid:1f10b - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid
```

Comment: Is there you want to share with us that you tried, so we do not suggest it if it does not work.

Comment: just signing out of itunes match and signing in again will fix the issue. I've setup new accounts, wiped itunes clean, same thing keeps happening.

Comment: what about using other user, or using Safe mode. Are you using Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is this process behind it:

```
gkbisd[256]: Unable to collect cdhash for /Applications
```

You will need to disable this in your dameons,  Apple introduced a bug with 10.9.4 mainly that bug is this process,  which is screwing up the keychain of passwords.

Comment: found this as well, basically resetting the db file. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6433525 So far no issues